# Using c++ 11 features and not compromising portability

Tags: c++, c++11

When starting a new project based on clang using c++11, how would you use new features like Variadic templates, Initializer lists, Defaulted and deleted functions, which are currently not implemented in VC11, to keep the possibility open to port the project to windows one day?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, variadic templates and initializer lists are supported in the last CTP (november 2012), so I would not worry about them. Not sure about defaulted and deleted functions, but I believe they will be soon supported (this is just my personal opinion though). For official information, see here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2011/09/12/10209291.aspx and here http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2012/11/02/visual-c-c-11-and-the-future-of-c.aspx

Comment: You could use `#ifdef`s, but I don't think it would buy you much.  You probably just want to wait until you are confident that every platform that you wish to support has the features you are using, and as always, try to abstract the details so that it doesn't matter.

Comment: well think with Variadic templates for example it is going to be impossible to abstract the details away, but they seem to supported at least for MVC.

Comment: You can sometimes 'fake' variadic templates by making one version with 1 argument, another with 2, another with 3, etc. You will have some fixed maximum, but usually a given project doesn't go arbitrarily high.

Comment: It depends if you'll want to build the project in VS *before* Microsoft implements the whole standard. Anyway, there are clang and g++ builds for windows, so it's entirely possible to use the whole c++11.

Comment: There are some compatibility libraries in `boost`, like the Boost.Move. Also the c++11 standard library was modeled after `boost`. But, what the heck, just update the compiler.

Comment: @user1095108, it's not true to say _"the c++11 standard library was modeled after boost"_, it was modelled on the C++03 library with a few additions taken from Boost.

Comment: It could be a matter of taste, but my impression is that many of the new language features of C++11 were influenced by boost, let alone the standard library. Boost is oozing out of C++11, at least in my view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft will be one of the quicker implementers. I honestly believe that. And you might too, after listening to [STL](http://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/stephan-t-lavavej) ("STL? Any relations?"). So, just use it.

or

use `boost` as an abstraction layer (currently implementing some variadic template-ish features via macros) and rely on that the boost-implementors choose a good implementation for your platform.

**Update**, after @NicosC comment: If you are starting with Clang or GCC, you can use those on Windows as long as MS does not support the C++11 features you are using. I would see that as "motivating MS to improve C++11 support" (even more). So, if you have the choice, use the C++11 features that improve your code -- easier to write, maintain and understand.

Comment: Quickest implementers? I'm pleased with how fast they're adding C++11 stuff, but gcc and clang are [far ahead of VS](http://cpprocks.com/a-comparison-of-c11-language-support-in-vs2012-g-4-7-and-clang-3-1/)

Comment: @slavik262: Of course! Thats natural, because its _the_ playground. No, and also not _the_ quickest, but among them.

Comment: Actually they're among the slowest, not the quickest. Which is why the OP is concerned in the first place. If you have to deal with Clang and GCC, you know you're good to go. With VS, not so much.

Comment: @NikosC.: You are correct, too. I should not have done such an superficial remark. There are so many compilers out there, but only a handful takes recent C++ seriously. There are some [competitors](http://wiki.apache.org/stdcxx/C%2B%2B0xCompilerSupport) (mainly on other OSes) and I'd say they are just in the middle, maybe a bit quicker then the middle.